# Macro to add 5 rows below the cell with value beta automatically and focus on the first newly added row using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Here I dynamically take 2 values "StartRng" --> where to add the rows & "RowCount" --> No of rows to be added.

Now I have starting range as "Beta"  & RowCount as 5 which is static now. I need to actually find the value "Beta" and assign this as startRng without using the inputBox which I'm using now. Then where "Beta" is present I need to add 5 rows below and focus on the first added row instead of the last.

Below is the code which I use.Is there any simple adjustments to be done so that I can get my desired output.

```
Sub BlankLine()
'Updateby20200123
'Author David Nithin Rajan
Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim StartRng As String
Dim RowCount As Integer
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "AddRows"
StartRng = Range("G1").Value --> use this code for dynamic value setting
RowCount = Range("I1").Value --> use this code for dynamic value setting
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", AddRows, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
Set WorkRng = WorkRng.Columns(1)
xLastRow = WorkRng.Rows.Count
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For xRowIndex = xLastRow To 1 Step -1
Set Rng = WorkRng.Range("A" & xRowIndex)        
If LCase(Rng.Value) = LCase(StartRng) Then
Rng.Offset(0, 0).EntireRow.Offset(1).Resize(RowCount).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrAbove_ ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy
ActiveCell.Offset(0).EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If
If LCase(Rng.Value) <> LCase(StartRng) Then
MsgBox ("Selected cell value ( " + Rng.Value + " ) must be same as 'Insert Row After' column data (" + StartRng + ")!!!")
End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I'm a novice in excel VBA. The code above is courtesy of google search and basic output oriented editions.

Comment: You can use the `Find` method to find the text. That returns a range which you can then expand using the `Resize` method.

Comment: I will try that. thanks for the assist. how about the focus? How can I focus after adding the rows to the first added row?

Comment: What do you mean by adding rows to the first added row? The first row you add will be `offset(1)` from the cell containing "Beta", no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what you're trying to do, but maybe this will start you off.

```
Sub x()

Dim rFind As Range, r As Range

With Sheet1.Columns(1)
    Set rFind = .Find(What:="Beta", lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False) 'find beta
    If Not rFind Is Nothing Then                                          'if found
        rFind.Offset(1).Resize(5).Insert shift:=xlDown                    'insert 5 cells underneath
        MsgBox rFind.Offset(1).Address                                    'address of cell under beta
        Set r = rFind.Offset(1)                                           'or can assign to range variable
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey SJR, this kind of solves the issue of adding the rows, yes. But my main problem is selecting the cell which was added first in the 5 newly inserted row.  That is, after adding the 5 rows, the active cell should be the first cell in the first added row.

Comment: Hey SJR , Thanks for ur simple solution -- I changed the code like this.

Comment: addr = rFind.Offset(1).AddressActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(addr).Activate

Comment: Instead of message box I stored the value in  variable and used that variable to bring focus on that cell.

Comment: Glad it worked. You should read this though as there is rarely any need to select or activate anything https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba